# Let $X$ be second-countable and $S \subset X$ discrete. Show that $S$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be second-countable and $S \subset X$ discrete. Show that $S$ is countable.

Since $X$ is second-countable it has a countable basis $\mathcal{B}$. The baisis for $S$ is defined as $\mathcal{B}_S=\{U\cap S \mid U \in \mathcal{B}\}.$

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is countable wouldn't that make $\mathcal{B}_S$ countable and furthermore since $\mathcal{B}_S$ covers $S$ would that make $S$ countable?

Comment: The only discrete spaces that are second countable are the countable ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open intervals with rational end points form a basis for the usual topology of the real line but the line is not coutbale. So your argument fails.

For each member $x$ of $S$ there is a member $B_i$ of the basis containing no other point of $S$ (because $S$ is discrete).  Write this index $i$ as $i(x)$.   Then $x \to i(x)$ is a one-to-one map from $S$ into the set of positive integers. Hence $S$ is countable.

Comment: By "of the basis" do you mean the basis of the subspace $S$ or the basis of $X$?

Comment: A basis for  a topological space is a collection of open sets such that eevry open set is a union of some members of the collection.  @Jen

Comment: What I'm trying to see is that by definition the basis for a subspace is $\mathcal{B}_S=\{U\cap S \mid U \in \mathcal{B}\}$, but I don't comprehend how these $U \cap S$ sets are singletons. I know that there is a definition for a basis of discrete space that's constructed from singletons.

Comment: If $x \in S$ then  there is an open set $V$ containing $x$ and no other member of $S$. [Thsi is the definition of $S$ being discrete]. There is a member of the basis contained in $V$ (by the definition of a basis). Hence there exists $i(x)$ as stated in my answer @Jen